# Pentaho: Javax mail errror

Tags: java, pentaho

I want to send email in a Pentaho Job and I am getting this error:

```
Job failed alert - ERROR (version 8.2.0.0-342, build 8.2.0.0-342 from 2018-11-14 10.30.55 by buildguy) : Problem while sending message: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not connect to SMTP host: email.....amazonaws.com, port: 465;
2022/04/26 09:57:17 - Job failed alert -   nested exception is:
2022/04/26 09:57:17 - Job failed alert -    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
```

Any Idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pentaho only supports TLSv1, and that has been deprecated for a while. Most SMTP servers require TLSv1.2 or TLSv1.3. You will need to implement support for TLSv1.2, or find an email service that allows TLSv1, which is becoming less and less common these days.